# Current instructions for using youtube api with oauth2 in C#.NET?

Tags: c#, youtube-api, oauth-2.0

I've been fumbling around with various pages of documentation and libraries and have yet to have any luck finding something current and the examples I have tried don't even compile. I guess v3 is experimental are there even real docs and examples for it yet?

these didn't help:
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Tasks.SimpleOAuth2/Program.cs?repo=samples 
(bunch of missing stuff what is Google.Apis.Samples? Tasklist?)

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

should I be taking a completely different tact? using version 2 (I guess without oauth)? all I need to do is server side auth and video upload.

Answer (score 1):

oauth2 was failing until I change my client Secret. then suddenly it worked. No idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Strongly-typed wrapper classes that Google offers?

### Strongly typed libraries for Google APIs

> The base API is a strong, robust API that allows you to interact with
>   all the Google Services that support discovery. This API is fine if
>   you are happy not having a strongly typed API and working with dynamic
>   interfaces.
>
> We recognise that a lot of developers want to access our API suite
>   using a Strongly Typed interface, not only for the benefits that you
>   receive via the IDE and code completion, but also because it provides
>   a strict, compiler verified interface to the Google services.
>
> For that reason there is a set of strongly typed libraries available
>   for all Google services. You can find those libraries here:
>
> [Generated libraries for Google services.](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/APIs)

The specific API for OAuth2 can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/APIs#Google_OAuth2_API).

Comment: it seems you need additional dll to use these as well? DotNetOpenAuth and Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.  the only example I could find using Google.Apis.OAuth2.dll (here https://developers.google.com/academy/apis/drive/drive-apps/auth/credentials) that code doesn't compile in vs2010 with the following errors: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'IAuthenticator' could not be found AND 'Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2.UserinfoResource.GetRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Fetch' and no extension method 'Fetch'

Comment: is there any complete, working sample code anywhere I can look at? I've been over everything and there are no C# examples that compile they all use other stuff that is not mentioned what it is or where to get it. I've tried to dissect the existing examples to take just what I need but I can't figure out what some of the required arguments come from. I've already completed this same app for flickr, facebook, and twitter so I'm not starting for total ignorance here there just are no working examples I can find!

Comment: It seems like your best bet is to try to get these strongly-typed libraries to compile.  Otherwise, it's going to be a long haul trying to write them yourself.  If you can get them to compile, you can poke each argument to see what it does.  If I have some time tonight (after the election) I'll see if I can get them to compile for you.

Comment: thanks. I'm taking a day off from this, I have other things on my plate here I can fill the time with.

Comment: I've moved onto trying this: https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/developers-guide-dotnet#authentication (server side section) I still can't auth though I always get a 400 error inside GetOAuth2AccessToken() (called from OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken) I can get the code= token back but then I try to exchange it for an access_token always get 400. I believe since I get the code back my 'parameters' are ok, but here is my code let me know if there is anything wrong you can spot. (http://pastebin.com/MtLwubm6)  any help?